# Some calculations on Transmission Lines

Tags: transmission-line, characteristic-impedance, reflection

I have to do some (simple) calculations for a transmission line. I was given a power supply of \$11V\$/\$22\Omega\$, \$Z_0 = 50\Omega\$, \$v = 2.2 \times 10^8 m/s\$, a load capacitance of \$1.124nF\$ and the length of the line is \$ l = 22m\$.

I have to calculate the values for \$v_1\$ (voltage at the input of the transmission line) for instants \$t=0.2^-us\$ and \$t=0.2^+us\$. For \$t=0.2^-us\$ it is easy to see that the reflected wave didn't get to the source yet, so we only have a resistance divisor between the internal resistance of the power supply and \$Z_0\$. Easy calculations gives \$v_1 = 7.64V\$ (I did a quick SPICE simulation and it seems to be ok).

For \$t=0.2^+us\$ I thought I could just calculate the reflection coefficient in the load and see what is the reflected component so I can finally calculate the voltage \$v_1\$. But I don't have the frequency of the wave (it wasn't given at least) to calculate the capacitor impedance and them the reflection coefficient and I'm stuck. Do I need to ask more information or is there another way to get to the result?

EDIT: here is the SPICE simulation.
[image: Simulation plot]
[image: Schematic]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using comma as a decimal marker or as a thousands separator?

Comment: He's using std EU notation.. remember the Cap =0 ohm ESR so appears as a short. so after 2 line delays of 0.1us Vi=?  , then tell me what is the Vout max?  (16.28V)

Comment: So what is your answer?

Comment: I get 2.97V at +200ns and since cap starts charging after +100ns Vi starts rising as well until the next reflection

Comment: Let me see if I get it: the cap will be seen by the rest of the circuit as a short during the transitory period but it will also charge when the wave hit and charge the line?

Comment: The same SPICE simulation resulted in  \$v_1 \approx 3.50V\$. I will try a little more during lunch time and see what I can get.

Comment: I would also through in parasitic inductance and resistance on the load end if you are going to do anything with this in the 'real world'

Comment: Well, a little more thinking and I realized that at \$t = 0.2^+\mu s\$, \$ V_{in} = 7.64 + V_{reflected-in-load} + V_{reflected-at-source}\$. Since the reflection coefficient in the load is (-1), I will have only the term \$V_{reflected-at-source}\$. Calculations result in \$V_{in} = 2.97V\$. Is this correct? Simulation shows that \$V_{in} \approx 3.50V\$. What am I doing wrong?